# Alter Primary key constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

In my table I have primary key on 3 columns (`name, dept, MobNo`).

Now I want to change it to be on two columns (`Name, MobNo`).

Is there any way I can alter the primary key constraint without dropping it?

I know I can drop old constraint and can create new but without dropping old constraint it is possible to alter it?

Comment: No, there's no "shortcut" - you need to drop all foreign keys referencing this PK constraint, drop the PK constraint, re-create it again, and re-create all referencing FK constraints. No way around this

Comment: @marc_s: okay..Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only and one way would be to drop the constraint with an Alter table then recreate it.

```
ALTER TABLE <Table_Name>
DROP CONSTRAINT <constraint_name>

ALTER TABLE <Table_Name>
ADD CONSTRAINT <constraint_name> PRIMARY KEY (<Column1>,<Column2>)
```

Comment: And of course: **BEFORE** you drop the constraint, all foreign key constraints that reference that table also have to be dropped, and those FK constraints will have to be re-created after the new PK is in place .....

Answer (score 0):

If you (probably) have dependencies on that PK, you will also have to drop them and recreate them. To have all this done automagically, it's easier from SSMS to right-click on the table, choose `Design`, and from there you click in the top left toolbar the button called `Manage indexes and Keys`. From there you make your changes, and at the end, you have 2 options:

- you close and save your changes (and it works fine but you don't learn anything)
- instead you click on the `Generate change script` so you can examine and execute the script later

(at least it works like this with my version 2014 of SSMS)